# Why isn't a method call executed when adding its result to a List?

Tags: c#, generics, ienumerable, iterable

When `Repeat(item, nr))` is added to `res` with `res.Add(Repeat(item, nr))`, the `Repeat` method is not executed.

Why? I used a debugger and it does not execute it.

```
public class Program
{
    public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Echo<T>(IEnumerable<T> src, int nr)
    {
        List<IEnumerable<T>> res = new List<IEnumerable<T>>();
        foreach (T item in src)
        {
            Console.Write(item);
            res.Add(Repeat(item, nr));
        }
        return res;
    }

    static IEnumerable<T> Repeat<T>(T item, int nr)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < nr; i++)
        {
            Console.Write(item);
            yield return item;
        }
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        string[] src = { "a", "b", "c" };
        Echo(src, 2);
    }

}
```

Comment: That's how iterator methods work -- they generate `IEnumerable`s that won't do anything until someone calls `GetEnumerator` and uses that. `Repeat` *is* called, but the only thing actually hit is the compiler-generated code that produces the `IEnumerable` instance, not the body of the iterator method -- and so the debugger doesn't show that code being run.

Comment: Try adding .ToList() to the Echo line:  `Echo(src, 2).ToList();`

Comment: @Neil that would just enumerate the _outer_ collection - the collections within the list would still not be enumerated. You could use `SelectMany().ToList()` to enumerate the inner collections.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enumerators built with `yield return` aren't executed until they are iterated over. So you'd need to have some code that iterates over the enumerator that's added to the list. Since you don't ever do anything with the enumerator returned by `Echo` (let alone the items inside it), the enumerator is never executed.